# Qt interface class

Tags: c++, qt, interface

I want to use a main like this:

```
int main()
{
   if (param)
      QtDisp *disp = new QtDisp(); //no visual result
   else
      SDLDisp *disp = new SDLDisp();

   disp->init(param); //displays the window
 
   while (1)
   {
      disp->change_color(colour); //change background colour
      sleep(1);
   }
}
```

It works with SDLDisp, now I have to create QtDisp.

I don't know what to do with exec() which is blocking. First, I thought to use Qthread but the display must be in the first thread.

Comment: Change color in `timerEvent` of QtDisp (BTW - bad idea to name your classes with starting `Q`)

Comment: Well, the program can use Qt or SQL, so I have to keep this main.

Answer (score 0):

Qt is event based driven framework. All gui part won't work without event loop. Almost everything, except, maybe brute calculations in another thread need to be done in event loop. exec() method starts that event system. So until you call exec() you won't be able to do something useful. In easiest way you can do it like this:

```
int delay = 10; //msec
QTimer *colorChangeTimer() = new QTimer();
colorChangeTimer->setSingleshot(false);
connect(colorChageTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), disp, SLOT(onTimerChageColor()));
colorChageTimer->start(delay);
int result = QApplication::exec();
delete colorChangeTimer;
return result;
```

Comment: If you'll give `disp` to constructor of `colorChangeTimer` (aka `colorChangeTimer() = new QTimer(disp);`) you can just do `return QApplication::exec();` without deleting timer object

Comment: @borisbn That's right. But I actually think that it's dangerous to set parent to object when object is not a member of parent. In this case it doesn't matter, but if disp will be deleted timer will be destroyed to, but the timer pointer can be accessed and no way to find if that pointer is valid.

Comment: So there's no way to do what I want ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the solution with timer and event loop?